# Programmatically configure VPN use .movileconfig

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension

I am create VPN using file.mobileconfig, and I can use VPN but I am need programmatically enable and disable VPN when I want,  is there a way programmatically setup this file and get opportunity enabled and disable or I am must create VPN like this https://kean.blog/post/vpn-configuration-manager or need use some other way???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is will be possible only if I am create cope of this profile programmatically inside app, but if protocol have a authentication use certificate it is maybe give some trouble because ios app api don't have permission to set certificate globally for whole operation system, for auth through certificate need take him in trusted CA.